# Is this Hermitian matrix an example of an unbounded self adjoint operator?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

I am trying to learn what an unbounded self adjoint operator is. Therefore I am asking if the following matrix $A$ is an example of an unbounded self adjoint operator:

$$\LARGE A= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{x}}}}} & e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{x}}}}} & \cdots \\
 e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{x}}}}} & e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{x}}}}}+e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{y}}}}} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
\right)$$
where 
$$\LARGE \underbrace{e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{x}}}}}}_n$$
and  $$n \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: An operator $A$ takes one linear space, usually a Hilbert space $H$, to itself.  An *unbounded* operator has a domain $D(A)\subset H$ on which it's defined.  Are we to assume you have $l^2$ in mind?  It's also unclear whether by $n$ you mean the number of the matrix row or column, and how $y$ affects off-diagonal entries in the infinite matrix.  The first step to see if there is something of interest here would seem to be to find a nonzero vector in $l^2$ or wherever which this matrix takes to a member of $l^2$ or wherever.

Comment: With $n$ I mean the number of repeated exponentiations as in tetration.